# React js web app not rendering properly in android browsers

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, webview

I'm trying to get my react web app to render properly with Android Browsers it doesn't render all the contents, it just loads few contents

Here's the screenshots on Chrome Mobile Browser :
[image: Google Chrome for Android]

[image: Google Chrome for Web]

Answer (score 0):

This depends on all upon the JSX code you have returned in render method of the react component, not on ReactJS.

If you want to develop a responsive website can start using Bootstrap or Semantic UI or some other library.